# Run wxWidgets on Cilon in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, clion

How to write cmake so that you can use the wxwidgets library under the window? I have to install it under VS2019 but I can't find anywhere how to make it work in Clion.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to work under MSVC {2019}? It is easy and straightforwrd - wxWidgets provides a solution to compile the library and a bunch of samples to study all the features needed to start development.And it also provides the property file so you can start developing right away

Comment: I have configured to create projects in VS2019 but I want to use Clion because I also use it on ubuntu and I want to create multi-platform applications.

Comment: you can still use MSVC on Windows. For *nix, you can use Anjuta (native GTK IDE) or Code::Blocks/CodeLite (which both have a template for wxWidgets projects). Nothing beats MSVC on Windows!!!